# Radial gradient on a node in cytoscape

Tags: cytoscape.js

I want to add the following CSS:

```
background: radial-gradient(circle at 3px 3px, green, black);
```

on a node body to make the circle shapes appear like a sphere visually

Referred http://js.cytoscape.org/#style/node-body - Gradient section & #2091

I've not been able to figure out a way to get them working.
Below's something that I've been trying:

```
{
  width: 30,
  height: 30,
  background-fill: 'radial-gradient',
  background-gradient-stop-colors:'green black',
  background-gradient-stop-positions: '3px 3px'  
...
}
```

What am I getting wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your code looks fine to me, maybe you have the wrong version? Non the less, here is a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) example of [how to use the gradient](https://codepen.io/steevokovsky/pen/NexzvV):

```js
var cy = (window.cy = cytoscape({
  container: document.getElementById("cy"),

  boxSelectionEnabled: false,
  autounselectify: true,

  style: [{
    selector: "node[id = 'n0']",
    css: {
      "content": "data(id)",
      "text-valign": "center",
      "text-halign": "center",
      "height": "60px",
      "width": "60px",
      "background-fill": "radial-gradient",
      "background-gradient-stop-colors": "data(colors)", // get data from data.color in each node
      "background-gradient-stop-positions": "25 75 80"
    }
  }],

  elements: {
    nodes: [{
      data: {
        id: "n0",
        colors: "cyan magenta",
      }
    }]
  },

  layout: {
    name: "preset",
    padding: 5
  }
}));
```

```css
body {
  font: 14px helvetica neue, helvetica, arial, sans-serif;
}

#cy {
  height: 100%;
  width: 75%;
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  float: left;
}
```

```html
<html>

<head>
  <meta charset=utf-8 />
  <meta name="viewport" content="user-scalable=no, initial-scale=1.0, minimum-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0, minimal-ui">
  <script src="https://unpkg.com/cytoscape@3.3.0/dist/cytoscape.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://unpkg.com/jquery@3.3.1/dist/jquery.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
  <div id="cy"></div>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Just another query- how can I feed part of stop colors from data.
Eg: If nodes was ->  nodes: [{data: {id: "n0", bg:'red'}}] I tried this & get error : "background-gradient-stop-colors": "data(bg) black"

Comment: I want to pick only the first color from data & keep the second color in styles. Eg: -> "background-gradient-stop-colors": "data(bg) black"

Answer (score 1):

Gradient support is added in Cytoscape.js v3.3.0 (make sure that your version is >= 3.3.0).

I tried an example with your CSS and it works fine (but I think the value of `background-gradient-stop-positions`needs to be a percentage between 0 and 100).

Can you provide a code snippet that reproduces your problem?